# Does interaction between predictors weights during LASSO and Ridge represent a true model with non-linear relationships?

Tags: interaction, lasso, ridge-regression

I faintly remember in class discussing that interaction effects, seen from LASSO and Ridge coefficient vs alpha plots, means that the predictors of some data set have non-linear interaction effects. **Is this true?**

For example, in my class project I know the data set I am working with has highly non-linear interactions between predictors. To disprove my null hypothesis (that the true model is linear), I plan to deny the null hypothesis by stating the interaction effects in the plot below

[image]

Though these graphs only represent a subset of the predictors that will be used, it is clear that there are some interactions between predictors. Assuming that the answer to my initial question is true, I would also like to ask the contra, **if the true model of the data is strictly linear would each coefficient weight monotonically decrease in the weights vs alpha plots above?**

Comment: How are you using the word interaction here? What is an interaction in a coefficient path plot?

Comment: By interaction, I specifically refer to the coefficient weights not monotonically decreasing. That when some weights decrease others increase.